# Display selection field in Django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I 'm trying to find a workable solution for my problem. I have found two similar questions answered before, but still I can't solve it. If we have a class like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Consumer(models.Model):
SIZES = (
('S', 'Small'),
('M', 'Medium'),
('L', 'Large'),
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SIZES)
```

And I did in my view and template like this (Learned from one tutorial)

```
***view with combined queries***

def staff_filter(request):
qs = Consumer.objects.all()
size= request.GET.get('size')

    # I have some other queries in between ....
    
    if is_valid_queryparam(size) and size!='Choose...':
       qs = qs.filter(size=consumer.get_size.display())
    
    return qs

def filter(request):

    qs=staff_filter(request)
    context={
             'queryset':qs,
             'consumer':consumer.objects.all()
    }
    
    return render(request, 'filter.html',context)
```

```
**template***

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="size">size</label>
<select id="size" class="form-control" name="size">
<option selected>Choose...</option>

{% for size in consumer.get_size.display %}
<option value="{{ size }}">{{size}}</option>
{% endfor %}

</select>
</div>
```

How should I correct it? Thanks!

Display selection field in Django template

Comment: shouldn't be `get_size_display`?

Comment: @YasserMohsen Tks for the comment! If you meant the html for size in get_size_display, I tried, not working

Answer (score 1):

You mispelled `consumer` in context in view

```
'consumer':consumer.objects.all() #You mispelled consumer here
```

Try this:

```
'consumer':Consumer.objects.all() # Consumer, first letter should be capital
```

I think you misplelled in above code so that's why you are not getting values on template

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried, still not working. I suppose something wrong with html file. The selection (drop down) does not function at all.

Comment: {% for size in consumer.queryset %} try this

Comment: I have a combo box, so in the beginning of the template, I have already started with for {% for consumer in queryset %}. Based on your last comment, I tried   {% for size in queryset %}, this time I got drop down, but it 's same as when I do query set in the shell, <QuerySet [<Consumer: 2022-10-27 08:58:31.596900+00:00>, <Consumer: 2022-10-27 18:27:57.661948+00:00>,

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any get_size.display() method in a template. If consumer variable is an object of the Consumer class then you just have to do like this:

```html
<select>
{% for val, text in consumer.SIZES %}
<!-- 
Here SIZES is a tuple variable of your Consumer class,
while consumer is an instance of the Consumer class then you can just
call SIZES tuple from any of its instances.
-->
<option value="{{ val }}">{{ text }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

If consumer is a variable from the context you are passing in your
view, then it's a queryset. So in this case you should loop over your queryset first, then call SIZES variable from every object inside the loop:

```html
{% for object in consumer %}
  <select>
    {% for val, text in object.SIZES %}
    <option value="{{ val }}">{{ text }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What about view, do I need to keep it like that or?

Comment: It depends on your intention of filtering, if you are filtering your queryset only once, then you can just leave it like this. If your filter is going to be in a template, where user can choose size and filter, then its better to combine two views into one, and filter using parameters from request.GET, or use django_filters which handles a lot of headache by itself.

Comment: @almo, I got you, then just give SIZES in a context separately. Take it from Consumer class `cons = Consumer()`. Then in the context  `context = {"sizes": cons.SIZES}`. And do whatever you want with sizes variable in a template.